# error installing arduino IDE on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, arduino

hi i'm following the next lines for install arduino ide , i'm working on ubuntu 11.10

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-avr avr-libc
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
sudo update-alternatives --config java  (select the correct JRE if you have more than one installed)
dmesg
```

downloads page on Arduino’s download page to get the latest Arduino IDE tarball (.tgz file) for the architecture. unzipped and ran it with the following command:

```
~/Downloads$ tar xzvf arduino-1.0.1-linux64.tgz
~/Downloads$ cd arduino-1.0.1
./arduino
```

Bur when i run it i get this:

```
virtualtouch@ubuntu:~/arduino-1.0.1$ ./arduino

(java:7733): Gtk-WARNING **: Imposible encontrar el motor de temas en la ruta al _modulo: «pixmap»,

(java:7733): Gtk-WARNING **: Imposible encontrar el motor de temas en la ruta al _modulo: «pixmap»,

(java:7733): Gtk-WARNING **: Imposible encontrar el motor de temas en la ruta al _modulo: «pixmap»,

(java:7733): Gtk-WARNING **: Imposible encontrar el motor de temas en la ruta al _modulo: «pixmap»,
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/virtualtouch/arduino-1.0.1/lib/librxtxSerial.so: /home/virtualtouch/arduino-1.0.1/lib/librxtxSerial.so: clase ELF errónea: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch) thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/virtualtouch/arduino-1.0.1/lib/librxtxSerial.so: /home/virtualtouch/arduino-1.0.1/lib/librxtxSerial.so: clase ELF errónea: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
    at processing.app.Editor.populateSerialMenu(Editor.java:962)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildToolsMenu(Editor.java:691)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildMenuBar(Editor.java:476)
    at processing.app.Editor.<init>(Editor.java:205)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:704)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:669)
    at processing.app.Base.handleNew(Base.java:565)
    at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:305)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:194)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /home/virtualtouch/arduino-1.0.1/lib/
mv librxtxSerial.so librxtxSerial32.so
```